# Conditional results based on two interconnected columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to use if in an Oracle query .

I need something like this , But cant figure the syntax , if i can get help

```
select process 
  from workstep 
 where workstep_name = 'Manager' 
   and (performer != 'Test' if end_time =null).   <----- this line
```

This means if endtime = null And performer ='Test'  then DONT show the record; but if, for example, endTime is not null and performer = 'test' then SHOW the record.

Comment: Do you want to show records for Performer other than 'Test' as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use IF in SQL with Oracle, but this is possible with simple BOOLEAN logic. You just need to negate two conditions at the same time:

```
select process
  from workstep
 where workstep_name = 'Manager'
   and not ( performer = 'Test' and end_time is null )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

```
and (end_time is not null or (end_time is null and performer <> 'Test'))
```

If we have datas like this (left is performer, right is end_time)

```
'test' - notnulldate

'test' - nulldate

'tttt' - notnulldate

'tttt' - nulldate

this will return all lines except  'test'-nulldate
```

maybe you want

```
and ((end_time is not null and performer = 'Test') or (end_time is null and performer <> 'Test'))
```

which will return

```
'test'- notnulldate

'tttt'- nulldate
```

Comment: this gives me the result where endtime is not null and performer is not test , BUT I want to see the result where performer is NOt test IF end time is NULL.. Means if performer is TEST then dont show the row of NULL End time , But if performer is Not test then DO show the nULL end time row

Comment: @junaidp This should return data when : end_time is not null and performer is whatever (test or not test) + end_time is null and performer is not test. Isn't it what happens / what you want ?

Comment: @junaidp see example of what's return to find if I understand what you want.

Comment: thanks ::   and not ( performer = 'Test' and end_time is null )    this thing worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query:

```
select process 
from workstep 
where workstep_name = 'Manager' 
and (performer = 'Test' and end_time is not null);
```

If you want to show all Performers where end_time is not null, then use the following version:

```
select process 
from workstep 
where workstep_name = 'Manager' 
and end_time is not null;
```

**EDIT**:

Based on your clarification, "if performer is TEST then dont show the row of NULL End time , But if performer is Not test then DO show the nULL end time row", the following query would get you the required data:

```
select process 
from workstep 
where workstep_name = 'Manager' 
and (performer <> 'Test' OR end_time is not null);
```

Comment: What happens if PERFORMER is `blah` and END_TIME is not null?

Comment: Then the record will not be displayed. This query will display only if PERFORMER is Test.

Comment: I want to see the result where performer is NOt test IF end time is NULL.. Means if performer is TEST then dont show the row of NULL End time , But if performer is Not test then DO show the nULL end time row

Answer (score 0):

> "Means if performer is TEST then dont show the row of NULL End time , But if performer is Not test then DO show the nULL end time row"

```
select process
from workstep
where workstep_name = 'Manager' 
and ((performer = 'Test' and endtime is not null) or(performer <> 'Test' and endtime is null))
```

> "This means if endtime = null And performer ='Test' then DONT show the record; but if, for example, endTime is not null and performer = 'test' then SHOW the record."

```
select process
from workstep
where workstep_name = 'Manager' 
and ((endtime is not null and performer <> 'Test' )or(endtime is not null and performer = 'Test'))
```

Comment: this gives me the result where endtime is not null and performer is not test , BUT I want to see the result where performer is NOt test IF end time is NULL.. Means if performer is TEST then dont show the row of NULL End time , But if performer is Not test then DO show the nULL end time row